# Применение ContentProvider при разработке "Менеджера паролей"

Tags: java, android, contentprovider, android-sqlite

Какие, на Ваш взгляд, механизмы обеспечения безопасности доступа к данным необходимо использовать при реализации контент-провайдера? А какие вовсе не обязательно, но возможно? 
Рассматривается сценарий, при котором будут иметься как приложения с предоставляемым им ограниченным доступом(только чтение некоторой части данных), так и основное приложение-менеджер.

Comment: Очень интересный вопрос, отвечу чуть позже - после того как выскажутся коллеги

Comment: Довольно любопытное проявление вежливости:) Буду рад услышать обоснованное мнение.

Comment: @Barmaley: вопрос под угрозой закрытия, создайте хотя бы заготовку ответа )

Comment: @NickVolynkin составил болванку. Ну реально некогда писать. НГ на носу - на работе все горит...

Comment: @Barmaley: аналогично с работой. Даже если удалят болванку, восстановить-то сможем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку ТС говорил о менеджере паролей, рискну сделать 2 предположения:

1. Содержимое БД зашифровано
2. Ключ дешифратор генерируется в момент логина юзера в программу

Это общие места при создании менеджера паролей (говорю как человек написавший несколько таковых программ).

Теперь обратимся к `ContentProvider` - они бывают либо `exported` либо не `exported` - разница между ними в том, что `exported` доступен внешней программе - в этом случае `ContentProvider` выступает как некий порт высунутый наружу программой. В зависимости от ситуации в порт можно или писать или только читать (полный перечень операций это стандартные [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) операции).

Рискну опять предположить, что раз ТС интересует способ защиты `ContentProvider`'а, то очевидно он хочет что провайдер был `exported=true` - иначе можно его сделать `exported=false` и забыть о проблеме.

`exported=true` провайдер нужен в менеджере паролей, если требуется каким-то образом "проникнуть" к БД паролей в обход самой программы и получить оттуда данные (ну например просто количество записей, хэши шифров или что-то подобное относительно безвредное). Рассчитывать на `ContentProvider` как способ защиты данных - бессмысленно. Любые данные в Android можно получить напрямую - достаточно иметь права superuser'а.

Теперь ближе к делу. Практически все пишется на уровне манифеста (ну кроме кода самого провайдера естественно), примерно так:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.mypackage"
    android:sharedUserId="ru.mypackage.shared.user.id"
    android:sharedUserLabel="@string/myapp">

    <permission
        android:name="ru.mypackage.MyProvider"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ru.mypackage.MyProvider" />
    <application
        <!--blah-blah-->
        >
        <provider
            android:name="ru.mypackage.MyProvider"
            android:authorities="ru.mypackage"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="ru.mypackage.MyProvider" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Здесь все более-менее понятно кроме пункта с `android:sharedUserId="ru.mypackage.shared.user.id"` это некая альтернатива вместо того, чтобы городить огород с `ContentProvider`'ом- фактически это декларация того, что доступ к данным приложения открывается для приложения с идентичным `sharedUserId` и совпадающей подписью - по умолчанию данные приложения в частном каталоге и закрыты для остальных приложений. Так если нужно получить доступ к данным, можно иногда обойтись и без провайдера и тупо открыть данные таким вот образом.

В остальном по сути создается ваш кастомный провайдер, который защищен вашей же подписью. То есть доступ к провайдеру будет иметь только приложение обладающее пермишеном `ru.mypackage.MyProvider` и имеющее такую же подпись как и ваше приложение.

Далее нужно иметь ввиду, что `exported` провайдер по сути это отдельный процесс, который запускается в момент установки приложения или в момент запуска системы и живет без вашего приложения. Соответственно, допустим такой момент, что есть обращение к провайдеру, но само приложение еще не запущено. А как мы помним речь идет о менеджере паролей то есть ключ дешифратор генерируется при входе юзера в систему. Что мы имеем? Имеем обращение к провайдеру, а ключа для дешифровки данных нет. Хорошо, если провайдеру не нужен ключ, а если нужен? Если нужен ключ необходимо запускать приложение напрямую из провайдера.

В общем провайдер должен знать запущено ли приложение и если не запущено либо завершать свою работу или запускать через `Intent` приложение.

Уфф вроде все.

P.S. Я бы считал, что `ContentProvider` на фиг не нужен в менеджере паролей - столько гемора будет :) - достаточно обойтись `sharedUserId`

Comment: разрешите поинтересоваться, а под фразой `"и имеющее такую же подпись как и ваше приложение."` понимается подпись ключом разработчика или же просто наличие в манифесте аналогичной строки - `android:sharedUserId="ru.mypackage.shared.user.id"`?

Comment: требуется совпадение 2-х условий: а) чтобы `sharedUserId` был одинаков б) оба приложения должны быть подписаны одним и тем же сертификатом [см. здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

Comment: ааа, спасибо, а то я подумал что только вариант а) требуется, тогда бы с секьюрностью явно были бы проблемы))

Comment: А как вы относитесь к варианту с использованием intent'ов и FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION для обращения  к приложению у которого этот доступ имеется постоянно?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33082/discussion-on-answer-by-barmaley--contentprovider---).

Answer (score 3):

Нашёл на китайском форуме по комп. безопасности - [Drops](http://translate.wooyun.io/2015/07/01/android-content-provider-security.html) (страница ещё доступна в кэше Гугла).

1. Установите `MinSdkVersion` 9 или выше.
2. Установите атрибут `exported=false`, если ContentProvider не предназначен для использования другими приложениями (похоже, не ваш случай).
3. Используйте параметризованные запросы к БД, чтобы избежать инъекции.
4. Если провайдером будут пользоваться другие ваши приложения для обмена данными, установите `protectionLevel=“signature”`, чтобы проверялась подпись.
5. Make sure Public content provider doesn't store sensitive data. *(прим.: мне не понятно, оставил без перевода)*
6. `Uri.decode()` перед тем, как вызвать `ContentProvider.openFile()`.
7. Protect permissions when providing asset files. *(прим.: тоже не понятно)*

Зашифруйте БД, например, с помощью [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/about/). Если этого не сделать, злоумышленник, получивший root доступ к устройству может легко прочитать содержимое базы. [Пример использования](http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com.by/2013/11/secure-your-content-provider-with.html) (на англ.) SQLCipher с `ContentProvider`.